# Project nested document using regex

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**Disclaimer: Totally new in MongoDB.**

I have a document structured something like this:

```
{
  "hd": [
    {
      "rd": [
        {
          "rm": [
            {
              "code": "a1asd"
            },
            {
              "code": "a24aer"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "rm": [
            {
              "code": "b16hwe7"
            },
            {
              "code": "b2z41s"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want return the subdocument that only contains, for example, "a1".
How will I approach this problem?

The solutions I tried so far looks something like this

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "hd.rd.rm.code": /a1/
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "hd.rd": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$hd.rd",
                    as: "roomData",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [
                            {
                                $substr: [ "$$roomData.rm.code", 0, 10]
                            },
                            "a1"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

but the query above doesn't work. I found out $regexMatch doesn't work with $cond, so I'm quite loss at the moment.

My expected results will look something like this:

```
{
  "hd": {
    "rd": {
      "rm": {
        "code": "a1asd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the desired result,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
    "$unwind": "$hd"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$hd.rd"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$hd.rd.rm"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "hd.rd.rm.code": /a1/
    }
  }
])
```

**ScreenShot of Mongo Instance**
[image]

Comment: what are you getting? I have tested the query and it gives me the correct result.

Comment: I tried it on my mongo instance, and it doesn't return any result even tho the nested document exist.

Comment: Are you replace the `collection` with your collection name and using the right database as default database is `test` in mongo instance.

Comment: @cankentcode I have added the screenshot of the query with result. Here i added your data in a collection `b`

Comment: confirmed it's working. there's an error on my part. thank you